# Does the function assume its minimum value at only one point or not?

Tags: calculus, functions

[image]

I am having trouble proving whether this statement is true or false.Can someone help me please.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
(p+r)x-q  & \text{if $x\geq \frac{q}{p},$} \\[2ex]
(r-p)x+q  & \text{if $0\leq x< \frac{q}{p},$} \\[2ex]
-(p+r)x+q  & \text{if $x< 0.$} \\[2ex]
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't we have $f(x) = -px + q + rx = (r - p)x + q$ for $0 \leq x < \frac{q}{p}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Edited. Thank you very much!